# OpenIddict front & back channel logout

Tags: single-sign-on, openiddict, single-logout

Can someone point me in the right direction about OpenIddict and

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html